# Error: Cannot export when target is not server. with next js and zeit-NOW during deployee

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am working a react app where i am using next js and express, I have choose zeit now for servless but when i deploying this facing error  **Error: No serverless pages were built**

**next.config.js**

```
const configuration = withTypescript(
    withLess({,
     target: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "server" : "serverless",
      cssModules: true,
      lessLoaderOptions: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        modifyVars: themeVariables // make your antd custom effective
      },

      exportPathMap: async function(defaultPathMap) {
        return {
          "/": { page: "/index" },
        };
      },
      webpack: config => {
        config.plugins = config.plugins || [];
        config.plugins = [
          ...config.plugins,

          // Read the .env file
          new Dotenv({
            path: path.join(__dirname, "../.env"),
            systemvars: true
          })
        ];

        return config;
      },

    })
);

module.exports = configuration;
```

using next version :    "@types/next": "^8.0.0",

**now.json**

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "web",
  "builds": [
    { "src": "package.json", "use": "@now/next" }
  ],

}
```

inside package json

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "next src",
    "build": "next build src",
    "start": "next run build && next start src",
    "export": "npm run build && next export src -o ./out",
    "now-build": "next build src","
  },
```

Getting error from **zeit Now** logs

```
preparing lambda files...
2019-04-19T17:24:04.955Z  Error: No serverless pages were built. https://err.sh/zeit/now-builders/now-next-no-serverless-pages-built
                              at Object.exports.build (/tmp/utils/build-module/node_modules/@now/next/index.js:305:13)
                              at <anonymous>
```

please help me here to figure it out.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have files in the `pages` folder?

Comment: Hi @GaëlS yes this is present inside src folder

Comment: Try to add `.js` to `/index` here : `  "/": { page: "/index" }` in next.config.js

Comment: Besides, isn't there a missing comma after "serverless" in next.config.js ?

Comment: @GaëlS I have test with .js to /index  but problem is same, also sorry about missing comma, actually comma is there but during adding code here i missed it here.

Comment: This link might help you: https://github.com/zeit/now-builders/pull/175/files#diff-7024b9ec8d56b5fa8178921c589bb9c8

Comment: @GaëlS man i have used latest version also but getting same error